# Spring validator without Spring MVC

Tags: spring, validation, spring-validator

Is there a way to use Spring Validator framework without using Spring MVC. IS the Validator coupled with MVC, cant we use the validator outside Spring MVC projects?

If no, Can someone suggest me a validator framework which has annotations and more like Spring Validator

Comment: you can use Hibernate Validator, it it a validator based on annottations and it allows you to create custom annotations

Comment: Nothing ties a Spring `Validator` to Spring MVC so why wouldn't you be able to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... Yea there was discussion in the team on chosing the validator. The requirement from lead is to find a validator with less coding and configuration and mostly having confgured with annotation itself.
Like if i use Spring, i need to give validatorUtils.ifEmpty() - instead of this can i use the annotation to denote the condition and error message to be displayed?